# IE transform-style: preserve-3d carousel

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I found a carousel demo use transform-style: preserve-3d,
like this :https://codepen.io/ImBobby/pen/uKbnl,
but ie don't support transform-style: preserve-3d,
what should i do ?

Answer (score 0):

Since the [transform-style](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-style) doesn't support IE browser, so the the sample not working in IE browser.

As a workaround, I suggest you could to use the JQuery plugin to create the Image Carousel, such as: [JQuery Three.js plugin](https://www.jqueryscript.net/gallery/3D-Rotating-Carousel-Plugin-with-jQuery-three-js-Image-Gallery-Threejs.html) and [JQuery Carousel.js plugin](https://www.jqueryscript.net/rotator/Simplest-3D-Image-Carousel-Plugin-For-jQuery-Carousel-js.html), they all work well in IE browser.